# Python: write coordinates numpy shape

Tags: python, numpy, shapes

In my python script I want to write coordinates of a numpy shape to a text file.
I import coordinates and element definitions and then use the numpy shapes to adjust the coordinates.

Then I want to write an text file where I write the adjusted coordinates.

With my current script however, it only generates 6 coordinates. I think this is due to my defninition of `s = new_triangle.shape` (see the script below)

How should this be defined so that all new coordinates are written into the output file?

```
newcoords = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 2.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [2.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
newelems = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23]]

import numpy as np

#define triangles
triangles = np.array([[newcoords[e] for e in newelem] for newelem in newelems])

#find centroid of each triangle
CM = np.mean(triangles,axis=1)

#find vector from each point in triangle pointing towards centroid
point_to_CM_vectors = CM[:,np.newaxis] - triangles

#calculate similar triangles 1% smaller
new_triangle = triangles + 0.01*point_to_CM_vectors

#Define new coordinates
newcoord = []
newcoord.append(list(zip(*new_triangle)))
s = new_triangle.shape

print 'newcoords =', newcoords
print 'newcoord =', newcoord
print s

#generate output
fout = open('_PartInput4.inp','w')
fout.write('*Node-new_triangle\n')
for i, x in enumerate(new_triangle.reshape(s[1]*s[2], len(newelems))):
    fout.write("{}, {}, {}\n".format(i+1, x[0], x[1]))
fout.close()
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: see my answer to your question earlier. `s[1]*s[2]` should have been `s[0]*s[1]`

Answer (score 0):

[Mr E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553404/mr-e) gave the answer previously:

```
#generate output
with open('_PartInput3.inp','w') as fout:
    fout.write('*Node-new_triangle\n')
    s = new_triangle.shape
    for i, x in enumerate(new_triangle.reshape(s[0]*s[1], 2)):
        fout.write("{}, {}, {}\n".format(i+1, x[0], x[1]))
```